# Why doesn't the ! (exclamation mark) work on MacOS?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, macintosh

I'm trying to use the ! (exclamation mark) to search my bash history on Mac and it doesn't work. Why doesn't MacOS have this feature and how can I install it?

It *does* work if I use zsh, FWIW. And !! to execute my last command also works. Here is my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

#Scala

export PATH=/usr/local/share/scala/bin:$PATH

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/

export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5"
# export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
# export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
# source /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: What exactly do you type and what the response from `bash` is?

Comment: Say my last command was `python3 script.py`. Then I start typing `!python3 scr` and press tab. Nothing happens, except that the computer makes that sound it makes when you are trying to auto-complete something that doesn't exist. @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: try `set -H` in `bash` and `set +K` in `zsh`

Comment: also, "bang" expansion doesn't work in `bash` with Tab like in `zsh`. Try typing `!py<escape>^` or bind some other key than `M-^` to `history-expand-line`, example shift-Tab: `bind '"\e[Z": history-expand-line'`.

Comment: @mosvy I'm not sure what you mean by `!py<escape>^`. Can you clarify?

Comment: press in order `!`, `p`,`y`,`ESC`,`^`. or `ALT-^`. that's the default binding for history expansion in `bash` -- look in the man page.

Comment: @mosvy that does nothing either

Comment: @Christopher `~/.bash_history` has history in it, yes. `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` are empty, `~/.bash_profile`'s contents are now in the post.

Comment: run the `bind ...` command from my command above, `set -H`, then type `!py` and then press shift-Tab. still nothing?

Comment: @mosvy that did it. How would I set it to tab instead of Shift-Tab? Or is that not recommended for some reason?

Comment: if you set it to tab, tab won't complete filenames anymore. do you want that?

Comment: @mosvy No; perhaps I'll stick with zsh

Comment: @mosvy if you put your solution into the answer box, I'll accept it.